# Add "Update Cart" and "Checkout" buttons to the bottom and top of the page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

How can I add the Ubercart buttons (Update cart and Checkout) to the bottom and top of the cart page ?

I currently have only on the bottom.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add them in your preprocess_page and page template.